# How to resolve external packages with spark-shell when behind a corporate proxy?

Tags: apache-spark, proxy, dependencies, ivy

I would like to run spark-shell with a external package behind a corporate proxy. Unfortunately external packages passed via `--packages` option are not resolved.

E.g., when running

```
bin/spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.5.0-s_2.10
```

the cassandra connector package is not resolved (stuck at last line):

```
Ivy Default Cache set to: /root/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /root/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/opt/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
datastax#spark-cassandra-connector added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
        confs: [default]
```

After some time the connection times out containing error messages like this:

```
:::: ERRORS
        Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/1.5.0-s_2.10/spark-cassandra-connector-1.5.0-s_2.10.pom (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out)
```

When i deactivate the VPN with the corporate proxy the package gets resolved and downloaded immediately.

What i tried so far:

Exposing proxies as environment variables:

```
export http_proxy=<proxyHost>:<proxyPort>
export https_proxy=<proxyHost>:<proxyPort>
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxyHost> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxyPort>"
export ANT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxyHost> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxyPort>"
```

Running spark-shell with extra java options:

```
bin/spark-shell --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxyHost> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxyPort>" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxyHost> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxyPort>" --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-M1-s_2.10
```

Is there some other configuration possibility i am missing?

Comment: here you are missing ``https.proxyHost`` & port

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Found the correct settings:

```
bin/spark-shell --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxyHost> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxyPort> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxyHost> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxyPort>" --packages <somePackage>
```

Both http and https proxies have to be set as extra driver options. JAVA_OPTS does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Do you know how to do this with spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster?

Comment: For me on spark2-submit this worked 
'--driver-java-options "-Dhttps.proxyHost=httpproxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=80"'

Comment: Hi @mtsz, I still have problem. I have configured the command with one of proxy which exists on [this site](https://free-proxy-list.net/). But it doesn't solve my problem. I don't know what to do. Would you please guide me to solve my problem?
[my stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744072/how-to-run-scala-code-in-spark-container-using-docker) and [my github issue](https://github.com/sindbach/mongodb-spark-docker/issues/5)

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi were you able to resolve this issue because I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @abheet22 I use some different jar files instead of the previous one.

Answer (score 12):

If proxy is correctly configured on your OS, you can use the java property: `java.net.useSystemProxies`:

`--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true"`

so proxy host / port and no-proxy hosts will be configured.

Comment: this is the easiest way and it works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me in spark 1.6.1:

```
bin\spark-shell --driver-java-options "-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxyHost> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxyPort> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxyHost> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxyPort>" --packages <package>
```

Answer (score 2):

Was struggling with pyspark till I found this:

Adding on to @Tao Huang's answer:

`bin/pyspark --driver-java-options="-Dhttp.proxyUser=user -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password -Dhttps.proxyUser=user -Dhttps.proxyPassword=password -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=port -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=port" --packages [groupId:artifactId]`

I.e. should be -Dhttp(s).**proxyUser** instead of ...**proxyUsername**

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxyHost> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxyPort> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxyHost> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxyPort>
```

to `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you need authentication to use proxy, you can use below in default conf file:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions  -Dhttp.proxyHost= -Dhttp.proxyPort= -Dhttps.proxyHost= -Dhttps.proxyPort= -Dhttp.proxyUsername= -Dhttp.proxyPassword= -Dhttps.proxyUsername= -Dhttps.proxyPassword=
```

Answer (score 0):

On  windows 7 with spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7 I set the `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` in `%SPARK_HOME%"\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\conf\spark-defaults.conf` like:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dhttp.proxyHost=hostname -Dhttp.proxyPort=port -Dhttps.proxyHost=host -Dhttps.proxyPort=port
```