# Spark & Scala: Read in CSV file as DataFrame / Dataset

Tags: scala, shell, csv, apache-spark

coming from the `R` world I want to import an .csv into Spark (v.1.6.1) using the Scala Shell (`./spark-shell`)

My .csv has a header and looks like

```
"col1","col2","col3"
1.4,"abc",91
1.3,"def",105
1.35,"gh1",104
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Spark 2.0+**

Since the `databricks/spark-csv` has been integrated into Spark, reading .CSVs is pretty straight forward using the [`SparkSession`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession)

```
val spark = .builder()
   .master("local")
   .appName("Word Count")
   .getOrCreate()
val df = spark.read.option("header", true).csv(path)
```

**Older versions**

After restarting my spark-shell I figured it out by myself - may be of help for others:

After installing like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676395/how-to-resolve-external-packages-with-spark-shell-when-behind-a-corporate-proxy) and starting the spark-shell using `./spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0`:

```
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
scala> val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("/home/vb/opt/spark/data/mllib/mydata.csv")
scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- col1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: what is spark here ? is it a spark context ?

Comment: Nope, starting Spark 2.0 spark refers the new `SparkSession`, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession - I added that to the answer. Thanks !